# How to Drag and resize Bootstrap popup modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, bootstrap-modal

Hi I am using JQuery responsive data-table and bootstrap pop-up modal,Both are working fine, I want to make that pop-up Drag-gable and re-size. Below code working for data-table and pop-up drag-gable, But pop up re-size is not working.I tried one sample pop-up code it is working fine with both drag and re-size but when I use with J-Query data-table that pop-up is not working.Below is my code, I commented jquery.min.js file, now responsive data-table and pop-up with drag-gable is working but not re-size is working. If I uncomment that jquery.min.js file pop-up will not work. Please suggest where I am wrong. should I need to add or remove any css or js files. Below is my complete code.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/new/new.js"></script>
<link href="resources/new/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/new/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/new/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/new/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
//datatable filter and proper 
<link href="resources/new/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/new/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> </script>
//filter every column
<link href="resources/new/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/new/dataTables.responsive.min.js"> </script> 
//responsive datatable
<link href="resources/new/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/new/jquery.min.js"> </script>  -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/new/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>  
 <!-- jstl tag library -->
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@page import="management.tcs.com.entity.*,management.tcs.com.services.*,management.tcs.*,java.util.*"%>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //alert("asas");
    showModal1();
      window.setInterval(function() {
            showModal1();
        }, 10000);  

} );
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" >        
function showModal1(){
    var j=0;
    var formURL = "<c:url value='/LiveUpdate1' />";
    $.ajax({
        url : formURL,
         data : {
            }, 
            type : "GET",

    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //Live updated values getting through ajax
    var table =' <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="98%"> <thead>';
        table +=' <tr class="success">';
        table +='<th>SNo</th>';
        table +='<th>Sender</th>';
        table +='<th>Recipient</th>';
        table +='<th>Delivery Status</th>';
        table +='<th>Read Status</th>';
        table +='</tr>';
        table +='</thead>';
        table +='<tbody>';
    for(var i=0;i<data.u.length;i++)
        {
        j++;
        table += '<tr>';
        table += '<td>'+j+'</td>'; 
        table += '<td>'+data.u[i].sender+'</td>'; 
        table += '<td>'+data.u[i].receiver+'</td>';
        table += '<td><a href="javascript:showModal(\''+data.u[i].message_id+'\')"style="color: blue;">'+data.u[i].sts.delivery_status+'</a></td>';
        table += '<td><font color="red">'+data.u[i].sts.read_status+'</td>';    
        table += '</tr>';   
        }
        table +='</tbody>';
        table +='</table>';
        $("#re").html(table);   
        //add here                          
         $('#example').DataTable( {
             "pagingType": "full_numbers",
             "searching": true,
         } ); 
    }
}) 
}
//popup table based on message id
function showModal(id){
    //alert(id);
     var j=0;
    console.log(id);
    var formURL = "<c:url value='/EndToEndServlet' />";
    $.ajax({
        url : formURL,
        data : {
            "messageid" : id
        },
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             var table1='<div style="overflow-x:scroll;">'; 
            table1 +=' <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="98%"> <thead>';
            table1 +=' <tr class="success">';
            table1 +='<th>Sender</th>';
            table1 +='<th>Recipient</th>';
            table1 +='<th>Mail Origin Time</th>';
            table1 +='<th>Precedence</th>';
            table1 +='<th>Subject</th>';
            table1 +='</tr>';
            table1 +='</thead>';
            table1 +='<tbody>';
            table1 += '<tr>';
            table1 += '<td>'+data.u[0].sender+'</td>'; 
            table1 += '<td>'+data.u[0].receiver+'</td>';
            table1 += '<td>'+data.u[0].mail_orig_time+'</td>';
            table1 += '<td>'+data.u[0].precedence+'</td>';
            table1 += '<td>'+data.u[0].subject+'</td>';
            table1 += '</tr>';
            table1 += '</tbody>';
            table1 +='</table>';
            table1 +='</div>';
            $("#resp1").html(table1);   
            $("#myModal").modal('show');

             $('.modal-dialog').draggable({
                "handle":".modal-header"
              });
         $('.modal-content').resizable({
             //alsoResize: ".modal-dialog",

             minHeight: 300,
             minWidth: 300
           });
         $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {

           $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
             'max-height': '100%'
           });

         });
    }
}); 
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background:#cdeaf5;">
<div id="re"></div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog model-lg">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h3 class="modal-title" align="center">Mail Tracking</h3>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="resp1"></div>
            </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="resp"></div>
             </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
</div>              
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

you can do that like below code:

```js
$('.modal-content').resizable({
      //alsoResize: ".modal-dialog",
      minHeight: 300,
      minWidth: 300
    });
    $('.modal-dialog').draggable();

    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
      $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
        'max-height': '100%'
      });
    });
```

```html
<head>
  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried this sample code this is working but when I use with jquery data-table css and js, jquery.min.js is making conflict so am i need to add any other js files? see My complete code, css and js files